# Is "DISKUTIL" available for Snow Leopard 10.6 MacBook Pro?

Tags: hard-drive, macbook, disk-utility

Is "DISKUTIL" available for Snow Leopard 10.6 MacBook Pro?
Is there a way to reach the terminal of OS with a keyboard command when start is running?

Comment: Please don't write in all-caps. Also, does this question have to do with the R programming language? If not, please adjust your tags. You can [edit] your question to address these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Do you wish for Disk Utility to scan and fix errors on your drive? You can boot into Safe Mode which does that automatically by holding down the `shift` key on boot. You can also use a recovery disk to go into Disk Utility too.

Comment: Well, in the meantime, I've found the way to enter the console mode, (That's what I was  seeking for, sorry not to explain clearly enough) unfortunately, I'm afraid not to be able to fix my problem this way. I think the easier way to fix it is to replace the hard drive. Thanks anyway for your help :-)